# Hi, I'm new to Python and a beginner all round trying to interpret this code

Tags: python, mysql, csv

```
def list_to_csv(filename, data, header=None, skip_writing_list_header=False, dict_write_header=False, deli="\t", enc='utf-8', qc='"', method='w'):
    import csv

    with open(filename, method, encoding=enc) as csvfile:
        writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=deli, quotechar=qc, quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
        if header and skip_writing_list_header == False:
            writer.writerow(header)
        for line in data:
            if type(line) is dict:
                if header is None:
                    header=[k for k,v in line.items()]
                    if dict_write_header:
                        writer.writerow(header)
                line = ['' if x not in line else line[x] for x in header]
            writer.writerow(line)
    return filename


fn = list_to_csv(Location.folder_path + 'media/dumps/' + filename, updates, header=headers, qc="|")
            
            with open(fn, 'rb') as f_in, gzip.open(fn + '.gz', 'wb') as f_out:
                f_out.writelines(f_in)
            remove(fn)
```

Hello, I'm new to python and trying to understand the code above and how the 'with' code works here. I understand up to opening the file.

1. open fn in read-only binary mode as give it a name f_in - the fn file is csv file that contains all the parameters mentioned in the variable fn.
2. I don't understand how gzip.open works here but it is given the name f_out.
3. I don't understand writelines and remove here.

Comment: I'm not sure what `list_to_csv` is doing. I'm guessing save a list to a file (by the name of the function) and then returning the file name to variable `fn`. Then it looks like it is declaring two files using a `with`, one is `fn` for read, the other is the filename in `fn` with `.gz` suffix.  It's using `gzip` to open so it's really just streaming the data from `fn` to `fn.gz` which is gunzipped/compressed. `remove(fn)` is just deleting the original file that was created so only the compressed file remains.

Comment: What is odd about this is that it writes to a file with the mysterious `list_to_csv` only to then pull the data back through and write to a zip file. Like... why not just write to the zip file directly. If this were code that I was charged with, I would go pull that `list_to_csv` function apart and make a new version called `list_to_zipped_csv` or add a new argument to `list_to_csv()` to say whether it should be zipped or not.

Comment: I agree with JNevill. It would be very useful if you could show the definition of this list_to_csv method, or where are you importing it from.

Comment: Hi both, I've added it to the Q.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, it's good to always post the whole program. I don't think this is the whole thing because list_to_csv is not a standard python method, so we don't know how it's implemented. We don't know exactly what it does and can only assume it takes a list and writes it to a CSV file.

GZIP is a data compression tool. The CSV file created by list_to_csv is most likely compressed to GZIP as default, so it requires GZIP to decompress and open.
You have these `f_in` and `f_out` names because these are file streams. the `in` stream reads, the `out` stream writes.

`with` keyword is a context manager, it opens the stream and ensures that the file is only accessed when the program actually needs to, and it closes it when its done with, so that other processes can access the file (concurrent access can lead to nasty errors)

`writelines` is a method of the output stream `f_out`, it will literally write the lines from the input file (which is being read by the input stream `f_in` into the output stream)

remove will remove the file passed from your system.